# How to get current anti-distraction focus in macos with bash?

Tags: bash, ventura, focus

How to get current [focus](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-a-focus-to-stay-on-task-mchl613dc43f/mac) in macos with bash?

[image]

Comment: grep for `focus` or `controlcenter` in `defaults read` and see if what you need is exposed under a domain and then use `defaults read <domain> <propname>` as per [apple docs](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/terminal/apda49a1bb2-577e-4721-8f25-ffc0836f6997/mac); as an alternative try locating the actual `.plist` file under `~/Library/Preferences` and then pull the value with `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`; also see `man defaults` and `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -h`